# Wildfly JMS message sending fails after failover of remote brokers

Tags: java, jms, wildfly, high-availability, activemq-artemis

I have a Wildfly messaging live/backup pair and a single Wildfly instance as application server (all version 26.0.1). I'm using Wildfly with the integrated ActiveMQ server as remote messaging brokers (not plain ActiveMQ servers directly).

For testing I use

- the helloworld-mdb quickstart example (https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/main/helloworld-mdb) deployed on the Wildfly application server with MDBs receiving messages and a servlet for sending messages using an injected JmsContext and injected Queue/Topic (I renamed the queue/topic and removed the @JMSDestinationDefinitions in order to define the destinations in the messaging-activemq subysystem configuration)
- and two simple JMS client programs: one for sending messages to a queue, and one for receiving messages from a queue (they just go the default route: obtain an InitialContext, look up a destination and a connection factory, and create a connection and a session)

My setup almost works. The client programs and MDBs reconnect automatically on messaging broker failover/failback. However, the servlet from the quickstart example blocks when sending messages after the live/backup pair fails over, and no messages are sent. It fails after around one minute with the following stack trace:

```
12:15:53,496 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /helloworld-mdb/HelloWorldMDBServletClient: javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException: AMQ219014: Timed out after waiting 30,000 ms for response when sending packet 71
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.19.0//org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.JmsExceptionUtils.convertToRuntimeException(JmsExceptionUtils.java:88)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.19.0//org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSProducer.send(ActiveMQJMSProducer.java:100)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.19.0//org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSProducer.send(ActiveMQJMSProducer.java:124)
        at deployment.helloworld-mdb.war//org.jboss.as.quickstarts.servlet.HelloWorldMDBServletClient.doGet(HelloWorldMDBServletClient.java:95)
        at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:503)
        at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.opentracing-jaxrs2//io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:52)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.18.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.18.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.18.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:275)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:134)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:255)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:100)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:852)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.5.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: AMQ219014: Timed out after waiting 30,000 ms for response when sending packet 71
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.19.0//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:539)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.19.0//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:443)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.19.0//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQSessionContext.sendFullMessage(ActiveMQSessionContext.java:552)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.19.0//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl.sendRegularMessage(ClientProducerImpl.java:296)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.19.0//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl.doSend(ClientProducerImpl.java:268)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.19.0//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl.send(ClientProducerImpl.java:143)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.19.0//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl.send(ClientProducerImpl.java:125)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.19.0//org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageProducer.doSendx(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:483)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.19.0//org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:220)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.19.0//org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:207)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra@2.19.0//org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQRAMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQRAMessageProducer.java:137)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.19.0//org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSProducer.send(ActiveMQJMSProducer.java:97)
        ... 53 more
Caused by: ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=AMQ219014: Timed out after waiting 30,000 ms for response when sending packet 71]
        ... 65 more
```

I followed [7.8.12. Connect a pooled-connection-factory to a Remote Artemis Server](https://docs.wildfly.org/26/Admin_Guide.html#Messaging_Connect_a_pooled-connection-factory_to_a_Remote_Artemis_Server), but I'm using http-connectors instead of remote-connectors because of using Wildfly as remote brokers.

All configurations are based on **standalone-full-ha.xml** with just the following modifications.

**Messaging live Wildfly server "messaging-node-1":**

- changed cluster password
- added replication-master
- changed cluster connection name
- added two destinations

```
...
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:13.0">
    <server name="default">
        <security elytron-domain="ApplicationDomain"/>
        <cluster password="${jboss.messaging.cluster.password:**changed-password**}"/>
        <statistics enabled="${wildfly.messaging-activemq.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}"/>
        <replication-master cluster-name="messaging-cluster" group-name="activemq-group"/><!-- added -->
        <security-setting name="#">
            <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
        </security-setting>
        <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10" redistribution-delay="1000"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
        </http-connector>
        <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-connector>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
        </http-acceptor>
        <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-acceptor>
        <jgroups-broadcast-group name="bg-group1" jgroups-cluster="activemq-cluster" connectors="http-connector"/>
        <jgroups-discovery-group name="dg-group1" jgroups-cluster="activemq-cluster"/>
        <cluster-connection name="messaging-cluster" address="jms" connector-name="http-connector" discovery-group="dg-group1"/>
        <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
        <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
        <jms-queue name="TestQueue" entries="java:jboss/exported/queue/TestQueue" durable="true"/>
        <jms-topic name="TestTopic" entries="java:jboss/exported/topic/TestTopic"/>
        <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector" ha="true" block-on-acknowledge="true" reconnect-attempts="-1"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
    </server>
</subsystem>
...
```

**Messaging backup Wildfly server "messaging-node-2"**
Same as above except replication-master replaced by replication-slave

```
...
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:13.0">
    <server name="default">
        ...
        <replication-slave cluster-name="messaging-cluster" group-name="activemq-group"/>
        ...
    </server>
</subsystem>
...
```

**Application Wildfly server "application-node-1"**
Replaced integrated ActiveMQ server definition with a remote broker and added external destinations. Notice the use of the default name and JNDI entries for the connection factory (for the EE and EJB subsystems):

```
...
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:13.0">
    <http-connector name="node-1-http-connector" socket-binding="messaging-node-1" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
    <http-connector name="node-2-http-connector" socket-binding="messaging-node-2" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
    <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="node-1-http-connector node-2-http-connector" user="JmsTest" password="JmsTest"/>
    <external-jms-queue name="TestQueue" entries="java:/queue/TestQueue"/>
    <external-jms-topic name="TestTopic" entries="java:/topic/TestTopic"/>
</subsystem>
...
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    ...
    <outbound-socket-binding name="messaging-node-1">
        <remote-destination host="..." port="8180"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="messaging-node-2">
        <remote-destination host="..." port="8180"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
...
```

The servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/HelloWorldMDBServletClient")
public class HelloWorldMDBServletClient extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8314035702649252239L;

    private static final int MSG_COUNT = 5;

    @Inject
    private JMSContext context;

    @Resource(lookup = "java:/queue/TestQueue")
    private Queue queue;

    @Resource(lookup = "java:/topic/TestTopic")
    private Topic topic;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.write("<h1>Quickstart: Example demonstrates the use of <strong>JMS 2.0</strong> and <strong>EJB 3.2 Message-Driven Bean</strong> in JBoss EAP.</h1>");
        try {
            boolean useTopic = req.getParameterMap().keySet().contains("topic");
            final Destination destination = useTopic ? topic : queue;

            out.write("<p>Sending messages to <em>" + destination + "</em></p>");
            out.write("<h2>The following messages will be sent to the destination:</h2>");
            for (int i = 0; i < MSG_COUNT; i++) {
                String text = "This is message " + (i + 1);
                **context.createProducer().send(destination, text); // fails**
                out.write("Message (" + i + "): " + text + "</br>");
            }
            out.write("<p><i>Go to your JBoss EAP server console or server log to see the result of messages processing.</i></p>");
        } finally {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(req, resp);
    }
}
```

Procedure: start the live/backup pair and the application server, deploy helloworld-mdb.war to the application server and load the servlet page in a web browser. For failover, shut down the live messaging server. Reload the servlet page in the web browser. Result: the web browser keeps waiting for around one minute and then receives what the servlet has printed so far ("...The following messages will be sent to the destination:" <EOF>).

Sending and receiving messages using the JMS client programs works after failover. MDBs keep receiving messages after failover. Just application server message sending fails.

I have unsuccessfully

- tried changing the timeout configuration values of the cluster connection
- moved message sending to a stateless session bean (in order to test transactions)
- replaced the JmsContext with a connection factory to no avail; createSession() blocks, then fails with "...Caused by: ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=AMQ219014: Timed out after waiting 30,000 ms for response when sending packet 63]"

```
...
@Resource(mappedName = "java:/JmsXA")
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

@Resource(mappedName = "java:/queue/TestQueue")
private Queue queue;
...
Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
Session session = connection.createSession();
```

Questions:

- Are the messaging and application server configurations correct for my setup?
- What could be the reason that sending messages using the injected JmsContext and Queue fails after failover?

I would appreciate any help.

---

Update 1

Just FYI: The application server notices when the live messaging server goes down:

```
17:11:40,908 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] (Thread-2 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)) AMQ212037: Connection failure to 172.*.*.*/172.*.*.*:8180 has been detected: AMQ219015: The connection was disconnected because of server shutdown [code=DISCONNECTED]
```

...repeated around 30 times and an Exception:

```
17:11:40,904 WARN  [org.jboss.activemq.artemis.wildfly.integration.recovery] (Thread-2 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)) being disconnected for server shutdown: ActiveMQDisconnectedException[errorType=DISCONNECTED message=AMQ219015: The connection was disconnected because of server shutdown]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.19.0//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl$CloseRunnable.run(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1089)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal//org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal//org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal//org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:65)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal//org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118)
```

Comment: Did you try setting ha to true on the pooled connection factory ?

Comment: @ehsavoie Thank you, just tried it with ha="true" - without success; same stack trace

Comment: When you trigger failover are you actually killing the server process or are you shutting it down gracefully? By default a graceful shutdown will not trigger a failover.

Comment: @JustinBertram So far, I shut it down gracefully. Now, I just killed it - same result. According to the backup server log at least the message brokers seem to fail over, even when shut down gracefully:
`12:39:22,134 INFO [...] ignoring quorum vote as max cluster size is 1.
12:39:22,134 INFO [...] Failing over based on quorum vote results.`

Comment: Ah yes. With replication the broker always fails over. My previous point only applies to the shared-store configuration.